# CORS error when trying to redirect user from a partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, cors, partial-views

I am working on an application written in ASP.NET MVC5 which require the user to be log in. The authentication works with Central Authentication Service (CAS). On the homepage, I have several partial views :

[Home page with partial views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvaD9.png)

I call a controller's action when I want to update the user's data.

It's working well, until the CAS session expires. If I try to refresh the partial views, I get an error :

"OPTIONS https://example.com/CAS/Authentication 403 (Forbidden)"

"Failed to load https://example.com/CAS/Authentication: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403"

**I think it comes from the use of Ajax to refresh the partial view and it returns me the login page, which is not on the same domain. How can I overcome this issue ?**

In my View I send the datas to the Controller with `Ajax.BeginForm()` and my controller returns a partial view, so that I don't need to completely refresh the page.

Comment: Sounds reasonable - if the user isn't logged in they shouldn't be able to request the view, partial or not. And if you have a whole login page then sounds like you shouldn't be able to request that via ajax, and it should redirect you to the login page before you can do anything else. So yeah that situation makes sense. It's unclear what you want/expect to happen instead?

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else... When the user is not logged in, he is correctely redirect to the login page (the login page is correctely returned). But when it comes to the partial view, the login page is returned directely in the partial view, leading to a Cross Origin Request error, due to the use of Ajax to refresh the partial views.

Comment: "the login page is returned directly in the partial view". Ok that's because ajax cannot redirect you. For ajax requests you need to return some sort of error directly in that scenario - perhaps a 403 page. Then your client-side script needs to handle the redirection.

Comment: Okay, I manage to redirect my user correctely thanks to what you said. I call a Javascript function on the OnComplete event of my Ajax call, which will test the status code of the response. If it's a 200, continue, else (if it's a 403 for example) redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: sounds like a sensible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome the Cross Origin Request error, I needed to handle the Ajax response. Instead of letting the login page being returned in the partial view, I call a Javascript function on the OnComplete event, checking the status code of the response.

In my partial view :

```
AjaxOptions ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnComplete = "redirectToLoginPage"
};

using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", null, ajaxOptions))
{
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

On click on submit, it will execute the action "ActionName" from the controller "ControllerName". Then, it will fire the Javascript function "redirectToLoginPage", which is :

```
function redirectToLoginPage(xhr) {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        //Whatever
    }
    else
    {
        window.location.replace("https://login.example/");
    }
}
```

This do the trick.